# Single-Sign On expierence with Azure DevOps on-premise with https

Tags: ssl, azure-devops, https

We have migrated our old TFS 2018 on-premise server finally to Azure DevOps 2022 on-premise.

When navigating on the Azrue DevOps site using http (e.g. http://ourserver:8080/tfs) we have a single-sign on expierence and users are authenticated with their AD account. But when trying the same with https (https://ourserver/tfs) always the AD credentials must be provided and no SSO expierence happens. After that the user is authenticated with the AD login.

Doing the same with the old TFS instance users are authenticated without providing credentials.

Is there an AD setting missing or is it a Azure DevOps setting that I have not found yet?

Comment: Have you checked the IIS? You need to configure your web site bindings to use HTTPS with SSL for your Azure DevOps Server, and obtain a valid certificate from a trusted certification authority (CA) or create a self-signed certificate. Also check if you have MFA set for the account.